# Exe generated by Pyinstaller is not working

Tags: python, pyinstaller, bcrypt

Hi I have used tkinter module to create a GUI application. For encrypting password, I have used bcrypt module. In Source code it was working fine, but when i create the executable using Pyinstaller , the executable was not opening. I am getting "Fatal Error".

So i tried to create a sample code(Sample_testing.py) which imports bcrypt as below

```
from tkinter import *
import bcrypt

root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

I have created exe using pyinstaller as `pyinstaller --onefile -w Sample_Testing.py`

when I open the generated exe, I am getting the error like this

[Noted Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoTB0.png)

I am using Python 3.7.4 and Pyinstaller 3.6. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Run the exe in cmd and add the traceback.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please try to be more specific in your questions. This will help fellow users to review and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Prudhvi I am getting same response as attached snapshot